# Fancy boxes with a border

Tags: fonts, fancybox

I have tried to find a good fancy box which would get me a background color and also a boundary color, but I seem to have trouble doing it. My output looks like this:

[image]

But the output I want looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get that outline with a color?

The snippet code I used is here:

```
\documentclass[serif, xcol=dvipsnames, aspectratio=169, handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Thanks!}
        \begin{center}
            $  $\\
                        \vspace{0.3cm}
            {\huge {\colorbox{yellow}{\textsc{Thank You !}}}} \\
            \vspace{0.3cm}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you try so far? Which document class you use? Please show MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem!

Comment: beamer document class: and here's the snippet of the code I used:  \begin{frame}{Thanks!}
  \begin{center}
   $  $\\
      \vspace{0.3cm}
   {\huge {\colorbox{yellow}{\textsc{Thank You !}}}} \\
   \vspace{0.3cm}
  \end{center} 
 \end{frame}

Comment: Please. move above information to question (edit it)!

Comment: anything specific, u would need? I posted the snippet I used. The output I got is posted above, but I want the output which has an orange border on it

Comment: Does the snippet edit I made answer your question? Also Thank you @Zarko for the edit! :)

Comment: Sorry thou, I am new here, Will need some time to try out all options and know how things work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `\fcolorbox` defined in the `xcolor` package which is loaded automatically by the `beamer` document class:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Thanks!}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\fboxrule{1pt}
%    \setlength\fboxsep{6pt} % if you like to have bigger space around text in box
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\huge\textsc{Thank You !}}
     \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

Answer (score 2):

Try withe `\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\huge\textsc{Thank You}}`